# Multiple Primary Key to connect 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, postgresql, entity-framework

I used to create an extra Id column in the following UserGroup table and then I realized it seems to be wrong.

***User:***

```
Id    |   Name     |
--------------------
1     |   Tim      |
2     |   Willy    |
3     |   Mary     |
4     |   Jonathan |
5     |   Mary     |
```

***Group:***

```
Id    |   Name   |
------------------
1     |   Bees   |
2     |   Ants   |
```

***UserGroup:***

```
Id    |   UserId   |  GroupId  |
--------------------------------
1     |   1        |  1        |
2     |   2        |  1        |
3     |   3        |  2        |
4     |   4        |  2        |
5     |   5        |  2        |
```

So, could you please clarify me about the following issues:

**1)** As there could be a single UserId - GroupId pairs in UserGroup table, using an extra Id column is definitely redundant and there is no need to use this Id column, is that true? May there be exceptional situation that requires using this extra Id column?

**2)** Removing Id column in UserGroup table, I need to make both columns as PK. So, how can I make that in EF Code First? Is the following definition true?

```
public class UserGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please set tag for exact DB you use. Not all RDBMS

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I use three of them and **the question is related all of them**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have asked 2 question:

**Answer 1 -**  In your scenario it is not required because you are keeping this table as relation between `User` and `Group` table. it may required in some specific condition i. e. you want to keep audit trail for your `user` and `group` mapping etc.

**Answer 2 -**  To maintain uniqueness of relations you need to create `Composite Key`. Your Definition should be like:

```
public class UserGroup
{
    [Key, Column(Order=1) ]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=2) ]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

[Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) for your reference

Comment: That is exactly what I want to learn, many thanks these good explanations.

Comment: On the other hand, could you also please compare this with the approach that @Yogendra mentioned? What about **not creating UserGroup table and just adding new column in User table as GroupId and making it foreign key?**

Comment: That approach can also be followed if one user strictly can be linked with only one group. it will not work if one user can be linked with multiple groups

Answer (score 0):

There would be a use-case for either solution you have above(with or without an Id column). Generally if the goal of the table is to simply associate the two sets of data, you would not need a new Id and you could use a Composite Key to define the Id for UserGroup. Reading can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations. It looks like you may have to use the Fluent API instead of data annotations from this document.

There is another case where you might want an Id column when forming the M to N connection for users and groups. If you plan to connect any data to the connection, it will be easier to have an Id to create foreign keys from other tables to the UserGroups. Specifically in your case I would think UserGroupPermissions might be introduced shortly after you create UserGroups. You could have a non-clustered identity column for this Id but i would not recommend it. If you want a table to have records with an Id it is best to use that as your clustered index and primary key whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have to two primary keys of a single table.
And no need to create a third table as UserGroup for mapping table User and table Group. Only condition that need to create UserGroup table when you are doing Many-to-Many relationship.
But in your case one user have only one group and one group can have many users that means there is many-to-one relationship.

So what your have to do is just add new column in User table as GroupId and make it foreign key.
And delete that UserGroup table.

Thanks.